# golang dispatch method call according to a map[string]somestruct

Tags: go, closures, map-function

Assuming I have lots of functions or methods with receiver, each of which has different type of parameters. I want to use table-driven method to dispatch function or method call. So I'll construct a table like this:

```
type command struct {
   name string
   handler func(parameter ...interface{}) // I don't know whether to use `...interface{}` is correct
}

table := map[string]command { ... }

func (c command)foo(f1 int, f2 string) {}
func (c command)bar(b1 bool, b2 int, b3 string) {}
// methods and so on
```

No matter what command I receive, I'll always use one statement like `table[some-command-name](parameter1, parameter2, ...)` instead of using the ugly switch-case structure.

Is this possible ? That different methods have different number of parameters is a problem ?

Comment: It's possible, but slow and highly discouraged, because it requires reflection. This seems a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you describe your end goal, rather than focusing on this particular solution? There's probably a more idiomatic way to handle it in Go.

Comment: Thanks for you tip. I've abstracted my problem into such simple case. Almost like this. So idiomatic way is to use switch/case or something else instead of table-driven method or reflection ?

Comment: I don't know the idiomatic way, since I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible ways. One is through reflection, that is `reflect` package and in particular the `Call` method. The second one is through function values and closures. I would not recommend the first solution, reflection is generally discouraged because it is complicated, error prone and expensive.

Solution through reflection (https://play.golang.org/p/3b5I77QMsFI):

```
type command struct {
    name    string
    handler reflect.Value
    args    []reflect.Value
}

var table = map[string]command{
    "Foo": {
        name:    "Foo",
        handler: reflect.ValueOf(foo),
        args: []reflect.Value{
            reflect.ValueOf(1),
            reflect.ValueOf("hello"),
        },
    },
    "Bar": {
        name:    "Bar",
        handler: reflect.ValueOf(bar),
        args: []reflect.Value{
            reflect.ValueOf(true),
            reflect.ValueOf(5),
            reflect.ValueOf("hello"),
        },
    },
}

func foo(f1 int, f2 string) {
    fmt.Println("Foo:", f1, f2)
}
func bar(b1 bool, b2 int, b3 string) {
    fmt.Println("Bar:", b1, b2, b3)
}

func main() {
    for name, command := range table {
        fmt.Println("Running", name)
        command.handler.Call(command.args)
    }
}
```

Solution through function closures (https://play.golang.org/p/8fM86lxalq1):

```
type MyFuncType func()

type command struct {
    name    string
    handler MyFuncType
}

var table = map[string]command{
    "Foo": {
        name:    "Foo",
        handler: fooClosure(1, "hello"),
    },
    "Bar": {
        name:    "Bar",
        handler: barClosure(true, 5, "hello"),
    },
}

func foo(f1 int, f2 string) {
    fmt.Println("Foo:", f1, f2)
}

func fooClosure(f1 int, f2 string) MyFuncType {
    return func() {
        foo(f1, f2)
    }
}

func bar(b1 bool, b2 int, b3 string) {
    fmt.Println("Bar:", b1, b2, b3)
}

func barClosure(b1 bool, b2 int, b3 string) MyFuncType {
    return func() {
        bar(b1, b2, b3)
    }
}

func main() {
    for name, command := range table {
        fmt.Println("Running", name)
        command.handler()
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I want. Thanks ! Here we can see the benefit of using closure. In this case, if we don't use closure,  I'm afraid it's not easy to abstract different function signature.

Comment: This is really helpful, however... if I wanted to pass an instance of a struct to my method that's being dispatched via reflection, how would I do so?

As in, if I had:

```
type DoSomething struct {
  // ...
}

command.handler.Call(command.args)
```

I get an error about type missmatch for this call.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming by this in 2023 and beyond... if you are searching this for testing purposes or you can guarantee all your functions have the same parameter signature, then you can simplify this greatly:

-- **Note!!! this does not solve the OP problem of different parameter signatures for each. Then you have to use something more like the accepted answer. But as this comes up as one of the top answers for "function dispatch map in golang" i figured this would be useful**

```
var dispatchMap = map[string]func(yourSignature type){
    "Key": funcName,
    "AnotherKey": anotherFunc,
}
```

So for example...to use this in order to create a dispatch map for table-driven testing inside a common wrapper but the tests are different and dont all use the same function...

```
func Something(t *testing.T) {
    value := "value"
    assert.Equal(t, value, "value", "Didnt Pass???")
}

func FailSomething(t *testing.T) {
    value := "nooo"
    assert.Equal(t, value, "value", "Supposed to fail!")

}

var testMap = map[string]func(t *testing.T){
    "TestSomething":     Something,
    "TestFailSomething": FailSomething,
}

func TestWrapper(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    for name, testCommand := range testMap {
        t.Run(name, testCommand)

    }

}
```